# Core Plot Minor Tick Labels on Zoom

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am having Axis Labelling Policy as Fixed Interval for the X-axis . Now on zooming I want the minor tick labels to be shown.Is there any provision for setting the axis labelling policy on the minor ticks that allows for this or in what way can this be achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a plot space delegate to monitor changes and add the minor tick marks when zoomed in far enough. Set the minor tick line style to `nil` to hide them or to a `CPTLineStyle` to show them. You shouldn't need to adjust any other properties, unless you want to vary the number of minor tick marks based on the zoom level.

Comment: Will try out surely. Thanks Eric.